# Wait Until Finished Loading iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi right now I have an application that is pulling from JSON tables and parsing in data and the loading times on this are sometimes unpredictable.  What I have tried which I thought would be good enough is to put in a view with a loading indicator and put it on a timer to fade out the view after a certain time period.  That works most of the time but there are still times when it takes longer than the timer to load.  I am fairly new to objective-c but is there a way to structure what I have to `waitUntilDone` before removing my loading view?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //Let Everything Load First Time
    LoadingView * spinner = [LoadingView loaderIntoView:self.view];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:spinner
                                   selector:@selector(removeSpinner)
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

What I am doing on my main view controller is bringing in a another view called LoadingView and then removing it after 1 second and that is all in my view did load along with other code.  Could there be something I could look into instead of a timer to wait for my JSON.  Here is my JSON in the same viewDidLoad

```
//Get the High/Low Price
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    highlowBitcoinsURL];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedhighlowData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});


//Get the latest price
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    latestBitcoinsURL];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedlatestData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

Comment: If there is just something I can look at that would be great!

Comment: Why not let `fetchedhighlowData`/`fetchedlatestData` remove the spinner if it's open when they're called?

Comment: oh thats true! I didnt think of that! Thanks that was a dumb question

Comment: I highly recommend you use AFNetworking. It's an open-source framework to handle communication and it's brilliant. It will save you lots of time and will help you follow the best practices.